# 2 regexs with the ? whch I don't understand

Tags: regex

I have 2 regexs with the ? which I don't understand. I can do them in PHP or JavaScript.

The first one is,

```
php > echo preg_replace("/o?/","X","bar");
XbXaXrX

> "bar".replace(/(o?)/g,"X")
'XbXaXrX'
```

The second one is,

```
php > echo preg_replace("/(foo)?/","X","foo");
XX

> "foo".replace(/(foo)?/g,"X")
'XX'
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

The question mark just means 0 or 1 times that thing before.

In case of `"bar".replace(/(o?)/g,"X")` it will replace all **o**s and nothing so after every letter nothing was replaced by **X**.

In case of `"foo".replace(/(foo)?/g,"X")` it relaced the **foo** by **X** and again the next nothing to **X**.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, but I still don't get it. But let me first ask: Where does the first X come from in the first example?

Comment: The X comes from the second parameter it's the replacement.